# Wordpress generated <scripts> in head results in 404 errors

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a new Wordpress theme, and just added the header.php, footer.php, functions.php, style.css and index.php. For some reason I have some auto-generated scripts that that return error 404.

I know it's not really a PHP problem, and the site still runs correctly, but it is quite annoying to have 404 errors in your page, no matter how insignificant they seem.

I have tried searching for this problem here and on google, but so far no dice. I would appreciate anyone who can help me on the matter.

I am working with Wordpress version 4.7.2. The following scripts are generated in the head part and return the error:

```html
<script charset="UTF-8" src="//addomain.men/code/pid/891042_IL.js?rev=494"></script>

<script charset="UTF-8" src="//addomain.men/code/pid/891042_ALL.js?rev=494"></script>

<script charset="UTF-8" src="//addomain.men/code/pid/891042_BNX.js?rev=494"></script>
```

I am attaching the php files themselves:

**index.php:**

```
<?php

get_header();

if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <div style="text-align: justify; width: 768px; line-height: 1.5em;">
            <p>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </p>
        </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;
else:
    echo '<p>No posts, write something :)</p>';
endif;

get_footer();


?>
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<header class="site-header">
    <h1><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"> <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
    <h5> <?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h5>
</header>
```

**footer.php**

```
<footer>
    <p><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?> - &copy; <?php echo date( 'Y' ); ?></p>
</footer>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
function shayR_resources() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shayR_resources');

?>
```

Comment: It may caused by some outdated or malfunctioned plugins. where are the links these 404 error refering to?

Comment: they are going to the script address on https protocol, for example, https://addomain.men/code/pid/891042_ALL.js?rev=494.

Comment: I got 404 Not Found from your nginx server on https://addomain.men/code/pid/891042_ALL.js?rev=494 ?

Comment: This is the problem. This is not even my nginx server. I presume it's being created by the wp_head(); funtion in the header.php (this is what I managed to glean from WP docs). My website actually runs on apache.

Comment: As @ChrisChen said it might be a plugin you are using. I suggest you make a clean local wordpress installation, install your theme and see if the requests are still made.

Comment: I have disabled all the plugins and even made a fresh wordpress install, those scripts are still appearing. It looks like it might be part of the Wordpress core

Comment: Ok. so I have made some checks, and it seems that these scripts are generated based on your internet locale. By that I mean the country you go into the website from. When I enter from home, in Israel, I get those scripts. When I enter from my server, which is situated in France, Wordpress doesn't generate them. This is very strange

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it turns out that an extension called "Youtube Mp3 Converter" was causing it. When I disabled the extension, the problem went away.